# Unable to run Vuejs w/ Webpack: component dependencies were not found

Tags: npm, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Why is it that I can't run my Vue script using webpack? I get this error.

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 11 errors                                19.32.28

These dependencies were not found:

* @/components/naven in ./src/main.js
* @/components/navtab in ./src/main.js
* @/components/artikel in ./src/main.js
* @/components/navbtm in ./src/main.js
* @/components/hero in ./src/main.js
* @/components/btmdata in ./src/main.js
* @/components/navbtn in ./src/main.js
* @/components/foot in ./src/main.js
* @/components/social in ./src/main.js
* @/components/contenthome in ./src/main.js
* @/components/Content-home in ./src/router/index.js

To install them, you can run: npm install --save @/components/naven 
@/components/navtab @/components/artikel @/components/navbtm 
@/components/hero @/components/btmdata @/components/navbtn 
@/components/foot @/components/social @/components/contenthome 
@/components/Content-home
> Listening at http://localhost:8080
ppabcd@ppabcd:~/server/vue-test$
```

I get this result in my browser:

```
Cannot GET /
```

Comment: Please provide more information. Explain what you have done so far. Did you install dependencies with `npm install` first?

Comment: i created this project in my windows. When i uploaded this project to hosting many error i get. I using `npm install` for remove error but not works. I manualy install all my npm library. But when all library done installed. I can't import all my component in my project.

Comment: It seems you don't have `node` and `npm` installed in your server! By the way, you can not install npm libraries manually because most of them have many dependencies that should be resolved with `npm`. If your project is running well locally, then the problem is in server side.

Comment: first time i installed npm and nodejs in my server. i'm installed my library for example axios library using npm install axios. But when all library installed i can't run my components in my project.

Comment: I run into the same error on one of front-end Vue projects.It was working a few weeks ago. I am not sure what happens. After upgrading the Vue (by running "npm install vue --save"), I don't have a luck yet.

Comment: I wish to know the answer to this problem as i'm facing the same. It's unrelated to "npm" and "node" installation, it's more of a webpack shortcut (@) one which doesn't understand vue paths, I didn't find any solution yet. Have you?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should update the "vue" version with the latest version.

or try this

```
import ComponentName from 'components/ComponentPage'
```

you have to add `@/`, when you use the latest version(`vue: ^2.4.2`)

but, I guess your error log means "your code is the latest version but, your vue is old version".

Comment: "you have to add @/" where exactly? Thank you for the answer but there are too many "I guess" and "I think" in there to be of any value.